# Use Simple Injector instead of Castle Windsor for Glass Mapper

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container, simple-injector, glass-mapper

I am sitting reading about Glass.Mapper. It looks nice, and is what I want to use for a project at work. We actually use Glass.Mapper for some projects, but we are in the loop for streamline our toolset, and have decided to use Simple Injector for IoC. Here: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial1 I can read that there exsists two projects for Glass.Mapper when using it with Sitecore:

1. Glass.Mapper.Sc
2. Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor

In the tutorials on the Glass.Mapper homepage, they only show howto use Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor, and they dont show how to implement a third IoC container that Glass.Mapper can use. But I think it is possible, when they expose the Glass.Mapper.Sc package, but I have not been able to find any explanation on what to do, when I want to implement my own, so I am starting to think that there is to much work in doing this yourself? Should I just depend upon Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor, and just do this http://www.glass.lu/Blog/MixingInIoc, so I can use Simple Injector also?

Or have I missed something, and is this infact the easiest to do in the world?

Comment: Or have I just completly misunderstood the http://www.glass.lu/Blog/MixingInIoc, and is this infact completly replacing Windsor?

Answer (score 5):

As a matter of fact, just yesterday I sent a pull request to the Glass project to use Simple Injector as DI library. You can view that pull request here: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/pull/123.

Do note though that the pull request was a theoretical exercise, because I was not able to set up a Sitecore environment and test this. But your feedback to the team is probably very welcome. Please send your comments [here](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/new).

Do note though that since Glass is a 'simple' reusable library, IMO you should be able to let it use its own DI library and use Simple Injector for your own project. There might be a few cases where you need to register a service both in Glass and in Simple Injector, but in general this should not be a problem.

Comment: The pull request is for V4 which isn't the official release yet.

Comment: @MichaelEdwards: And the code for the pull request does not work for v3?

Comment: Uhm, I could infact take your simple injector handler and installer,and use it? Or try to? And then wait for the v4 to come out.

Comment: No the interface you implemented isn't in v3. We have also just updated this again today based on feedback.